# how to do a selection of specific edges on duplicated objects in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I’m new to python, so I'm sorry if my question seems to be silly.
But, I'll be grateful if someone could help.

I'm writing a script in **Maya Python**.
I have a set of duplicated meshes. I need to select certain poly edges and convert them into curves.

I've managed to write the last part of converting the polyEdge to Curve, but struggling to  write the wildcard selection.

I was thinking to write the following way:

```
list = [list of objects I want to get edges of]

for i in list:
      pm.select()
```

Kind of like that,
But to be honest I don't know what I'm doing here.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

here is an example

```
# list of your duplicates
myDuplicatedMeshes = ['pShpere1_dup']
# select your edges in the viewport for detecting which edges to transfer
edgeInputList = cmds.ls(sl=True)
# collect the edges ids
edgeIds = [i.split('.')[-1] for i in edgeInputList]
# loop into the duplicated
for dup in myDuplicatedMeshes:
    # give the edge ids
    targeted_edges = ['{}.{}'.format(dup, id) for id in edgeIds]
    # convert to curve
    curveBuilded = cmds.polyToCurve(targeted_edges, form=2, degree=3)
```

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much! I'll give it a try!

Comment: If you find the answer works for you come back and mark it 'accepted' so other people finding it via google know it's the way to go